# Execute Asynchronous call after return statement Reactive Core + Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am Using Spring Boot 2 as my rest layer.
I was wondering if there is a way to preform
this with reactive Core  in java?

```
1)Response response = Response.ok.(Object).Build;
2)new Thread() -> {Some code that takes some time}
3)return response;
```

I want to execute this asynchronously. So when we hit step 3 and return the 
response, step 2 is still be executing. This is what I kind of did so far but its not really working. Step 2 stops after we hit step 3.

```
Mono<Response> Resp
Mono<Void> void
return Resp.Block();
```

:)

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want to execute `Some code that takes some time` in a "fire-and-forget" fashion, having no effect on the timing of the response being returned?

Comment: yes! exactly Fire and forget, having no effect on the the response.

Comment: There's no big win in trying to do that reactively then, unless the somecode is already a Mono. You could always use a doOn* in which you subscribe to said mono

Comment: check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566465/fire-and-forget-with-reactor) - may help you.