# WebFlux - handle each item asynchronously before returning

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am fairly new to WebFlux and I am looking for what seems to be a pretty normal usage pattern. Basically what I have is a Spring Controller which returns a **Flux< A >** (where **A** is a row fetched from the DB using R2DBC). I want to do an async operation on each received object (for instance I want to send a push notification for each object, for which I also need to make a call to the DB for the users push token and then send the push). The operations should be done asynchronously, so the API end-users receive their data with no delay. Is there some pattern for this already?

Comment: Is this for a controller? You can just use map and return the Flux.

Comment: The operation I am doing for each item could take a while, map is synchronous so it is not an option.

Comment: You need to use flatmap operator, add  code sample for more details.

Comment: @Veles "The operations should be done asynchronously, so the API end-users receive their data with no delay" - do you want a "fire and forget" type approach, or something else? A code sample would help tremendously here.

Comment: If you need fire-and-forget, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57569541/6051176

Comment: Yes, thats it Martin :-) Please add it as the answer, I will mark it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fire and forget with reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566465/fire-and-forget-with-reactor)