# Spring reactor - trigger method with delay without waiting for the results

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

In my spring webflux I want to create a method `mainFlow()` which returns email address from the `getToAddress()` method. Each time someone executes the  `mainFlow()` I want it to trigger execution of the method `sendEmail()` with 5 seconds delay. I don't want to wait for the results of the `sendEmail` I just want it to be executed aside the mainFlow. How to do it ?

Can I trigger functions on a separate thread or should I create some sort of blocking quqeue and consumer of its to be able to do it ?

```
fun mainFlow(): Mono<String> {
  return getToAddress()
      .doOnNext{
      // I want the getToAddress() result to be immediately return + I want the sendEmail message to be executed with 5 seconds delay
         sendEmail(it)
      }

}


private fun getToAddress(): Mono<String> {
      ...
    

private fun sendEmail(toAddress: String): Mono<Void> {
      ...
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566465/fire-and-forget-with-reactor - sounds like you probably want a "fire and forget" type which you can get by subscribing to the inner mono in `doOnNext()`.