# How to complete a reactive chain while branching out another process that will finish after complete

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

using Spring boot with Webflux. What I need to do is the following:

When I get a request I need to call another REST endpoint on another service and then I need to have a delay of 30 seconds after which I should call the same endpoint but with slightly different data.

I can't just use `.then(delay)` because this means the request I got will complete in 30+ seconds and this will cause a timeout on the calling end.

So I am wondering how to branch out and spin up another process that will wait for 30 seconds and call the necessary endpoint while I let the reactive chain, that was initialised when I got a REST call against my service, to complete?

Small visualisation below:

```
Caller             My Service            Other service
|                     |                       |
|                     |                       |
|-----REST call------>|                       |
|                     |-------1st call------->|
|<---response 200-----|                       |
|                     |                       |
|                     |                       |
|                     |   30 seconds          |
|                     |                       |
|                     |                       |
|                     |-------2nd call------->|
|                     |                       |
|                     |                       |
```

Hope it is clear.

Thanks!

Comment: It cannot be done within "REST call" flux. You have to schedule 2nd call somehow manually. For example, take an Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() and submit a task to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fire and forget with reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566465/fire-and-forget-with-reactor)

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this, basically it should be quite close to what you want to achieve

```java
@GetMapping("/make-calls")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> makeCalls() {
    return myService.makeCall() // call first service
            .map(result -> ResponseEntity.ok(result)) // map the result to response
            // after success, we call subscribe() to this chain from another thread, so that the response will be returned immediately.
            // the call will be executed after 30 seconds
            .doOnSuccess(__ -> Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(30L)) 
                    .flatMap(___ -> otherService.makeCall())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                    .subscribe()
            );
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks!